# Add suggestions to custom keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I work custom keyboard
  And I want to know how I add suggestions into my keyboard, I saw that a couple of questions on this issue and no one receives an answer whether you can get help or even just the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)isDictionaryWord:(NSString*)word {   

UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, word.length);    
arrPredectiveText=[checker completionsForPartialWordRange:searchRange inString:word language:currentLanguage];  

}
```

read this article too http://atmac.org/ios-8-keyboards-for-accessibility

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I'm glad you explain a little more about how to integrate it on my keyboard

Comment: Have the code here and I can not combine that my keyboard https://github.com/Kamaros/ELDeveloperKeyboard

Comment: zero knowledge in swift, sorry bro

Comment: How do you do that dude?
It will work for me on any language?

Comment: are you asking or telling ?

Comment: do some R&D bro, i am working on this since last 5 days only

Comment: `AnilPrasad` it is advised you don't ask and/or share email addresses on here. If they haven't got the reputation for chat then you will just have to live with comments and update your answer at the end. And @DevelopApple please don't offer to pay users we aren't here to be hired we are just here to help with small issues and if you have a new question that is different from this one please ask another question don't start another question here in comments. Both please read rules about answering and asking and take look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/ about do's and don'ts

Comment: Also @AnilPrasad The user might ask less questions if you add a description to your answer. Please don't just post code please include description of your code so others can learn from it instead of just copying and pasting and not having a clue what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much new here, I just

Comment: @DevelopApple also your question specifically asks for swift and this answer is not in swift so is incorrect so it shouldn't be chosen as the correct answer (Green Tick). This will wrong indicate to other users that are searching for help around this that this answer is correct for what you asked. It is not correct though on what you asked it is clearly objective-c when you asked for swift. This isn't helping anyone.

Comment: I thought I should highlight the person that helps you ..
And this man said to me, it helps me personally so I mark it

Comment: @DevelopApple No that's not the way it works mate sorry. If the user helped you then yeah by all means +1 the answer but the answer should only be chosen as correct if and only if they actually resolved your problem and since you specifically ask for swift and this answer is in objective-c it is not the right answer, it is incorrect. So you are wrongly telling other users that this answer is correct even though it isn't. If another user looks for a similar question and finds this it will be wrong so will ask the exact same question again which causes duplicate questions which isn't wanted.